# How to show the file folders in GridView in Android?

Tags: android, file, gridview

I have a directory under which I have many folders which I want to show on `GridView` in an Activity.

I have extracted the path for the folders and the title, but drawing blanks on How to implement it in `GridView`.
My code is here for `GridView` implementation.

```
String[] albumNameOnly=thisIntent.getStringArrayExtra("AlbumString");
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        columnWidth = getScreenWidth();
        InitilizeGridLayout(columnWidth);
//The initialize grid is shown below.
        MyAlbumAdapter myAlbumAdapter;
        Log.e("Starting the Adapter","+++");
        myAlbumAdapter = new MyAlbumAdapter(getApplicationContext(), columnWidth,albumNameOnly);
        gridView.setAdapter(myAlbumAdapter);
    }




public int getScreenWidth() {
    int columnWidth;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    final Point point = new Point();
    try {
        display.getSize(point);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
        point.x = display.getWidth();
        point.y = display.getHeight();
    }
    columnWidth = point.x;
    return columnWidth;
}




private void InitilizeGridLayout(int screenWidth) {
    Resources r = getResources();
    float padding = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            GRID_PADDING, r.getDisplayMetrics());

    columnWidth = (int) ((screenWidth - ((NUM_OF_COLUMNS + 1) * padding)) / NUM_OF_COLUMNS);

    gridView.setNumColumns(NUM_OF_COLUMNS);
    gridView.setColumnWidth(columnWidth);
    gridView.setStretchMode(GridView.NO_STRETCH);
    gridView.setPadding((int) padding, (int) padding, (int) padding,
            (int) padding);
    gridView.setHorizontalSpacing((int) padding);
    gridView.setVerticalSpacing((int) padding);
}
```

And my `AlbumAdapter` is Below.
Right now I just want them in `GridView` that's why I am setting it to a drawable in `setResource` for `ImageView`.

```
public MyAlbumAdapter(Context context, int columnWidth, String[] albumNameOnly) {
        this.context = context;
        Log.e("My Adapter Called", "++++");
        this.columnWidth = columnWidth;
        this.albumNameOnly = albumNameOnly;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.e("Size of Directory", "++ " + albumNameOnly.length);
        return MainActivity.directoryPath.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View myGrid;
        final ImageView imageView;
        final TextView textView;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null) {
            myGrid = new View(context);
            myGrid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.album_grid_activity_layout, null);
            imageView = (ImageView) myGrid.findViewById(R.id.no_image_placeholder);
            textView = (TextView) myGrid.findViewById(R.id.album_title_main);

            //         myImageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(200, 200));
            //           myImageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
//            myImageView.setPadding(1, 1, 1, 1);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(columnWidth, columnWidth));
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
            Log.e("++++", "AlbuM Name to be displayed" + albumNameOnly[position]);
            textView.setText(albumNameOnly[position]);

        } else {
            myGrid = (View) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return myGrid;
    }
```

Here is my `GridView` Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/grid_view"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="#fffff">
</GridView>
```

And the layout on which I am setting the image and title for it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/no_image_placeholder"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/album_title_main"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="12dip"
        android:background="@android:color/tertiary_text_light"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/no_image_placeholder"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/no_image_placeholder"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me in this issue.
I will be very thankful for the help.

Comment: Have you checked that String[] albumNameOnly length is > 0 or not null?

Comment: Yes, for now it has 3 strings in it.

Comment: @Anand Vardhan : Any special reason why you are setting gridview properties programmatically even though you placed gridView in layout xml?? Can you set some background color for GridView and confirm is it actually being placed on your layout or not ? If yes what is its frame ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari yes, i am curious too, since Anand setting imageView's properties programmatically

Comment: @Anand Vardhan : One more issue I noticed is in getView implementation if (convertView == null) else part is wrong :) Anand has written myGrid = (View) convertView.getTag(); infact itshould be myGrid = convertView :) You have not set anything as Tag to your view and in else part you are assigning Convert view's tag as view which is wrong :) if convert view is not null you should return the convert view itself and not it's tag :)

Comment: @HendraWijayaDjiono : Yeah :) lets wait for his response :)

Comment: @AnandVardhan : Have you changed else part of getView ?? Is it working now??

Comment: @Sadeep Bhandari Yup, it was a recent change I made, but it was not working too. Previously I have used myGrid = convertView, but still it was not working. I am sorry I didn't uploaded the layout previously.

Comment: try to use ViewHolder pattern from my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use ViewHolder pattern to get better memory consumption and performance on your adapter.

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView;
    ImageView imageView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if(convertView==null){
        // inflate the layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        // well set up the ViewHolder
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
        viewHolder.textView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        //just need to set the image once, because all images will be same
        //you can also set the image directly from XML
        viewHolder.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);

        // store the holder with the view.
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }else{
        // we will avoid call findViewById() on resource everytime
        // just use the viewHolder
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // object item based on the position
    ObjectItem objectItem = data[position];

    // assign values if the object is not null
    if(objectItem != null) {
        viewHolder.textView.setText(objectItem.itemName);
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Your problem is you call

```
    else {
        myGrid = (View) convertView.getTag();
    }
```

while you didn't set the tag to your convertView with ViewHolder pattern

Comment: Thank You Hendra. I will implement it and let you know if it's working.

Comment: FYI, ViewHolder is not a View itself, but it will hold reference to the View items to be re-useable by the Adapter

Comment: That is your data, which is String[] albumNameOnly in your case

Comment: glad that i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the RecyclerView for showing the file folders as Grid in the Activity.

```
public class NewAlbumAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    String[] allAlbumName;
    File[] filePathToAllAlbums;
    ArrayList<File> firstImageOfAllFile;
    Context context;
    private static final int TYPE_HEADER = 2;
    private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 1;
    int countOfAlbums;
    RecyclerViewClickListener recyclerViewClickListener;


    public interface RecyclerViewClickListener {
        void onClick(View view, int position);

        void onLongClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public NewAlbumAdapter(Context context, File[] filePathToAllAlbums, String[] allAlbumName, int countOfAlbums, ArrayList<File> firstImageOfAllFile) {
        this.context = context;
        this.filePathToAllAlbums = filePathToAllAlbums;
        this.allAlbumName = allAlbumName;
        this.countOfAlbums = countOfAlbums;
        this.firstImageOfAllFile = firstImageOfAllFile;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;

//        view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.no_photo_album,parent,false);
//        MyViewHolder myViewHolder=new MyViewHolder(view);
//        return myViewHolder;
//        if (viewType == TYPE_ITEM) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.no_photo_album, parent, false);
        return RecyclerItemViewHolder.newInstance(view);
//        } else if (viewType == TYPE_HEADER) {
//            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.recycler_header, parent, false);
//            return new RecyclerHeaderViewHolder(view);
//        }
//        throw new RuntimeException("There is no type that matches the type " + viewType + " + make sure your using types    correctly");
    }

    public int getBasicItemCount() {
        return countOfAlbums == 0 ? 0 : allAlbumName.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return getBasicItemCount();
//        return getBasicItemCount()+1; //Use this for header

    }



    public boolean isPositionHeader(int position) {
        return position == 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        View view;
        RecyclerItemViewHolder itemHolder = (RecyclerItemViewHolder) holder;
        if (firstImageOfAllFile.get(position) != null) {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(firstImageOfAllFile.get(position).toString());
            itemHolder.setImageView(bitmap);
        } else {
            itemHolder.setImageView(R.drawable.no_photo_icon);
        }
        itemHolder.setAlbumTitle(allAlbumName[position]);
        itemHolder.setNumberOfPic(String.valueOf(filePathToAllAlbums[position].list().length));

    }
}

Right now I am not showing any images which are currently there in the folders, so I am showing it with the drawable icon.

And the items are being feeded into it using a item feeder.

public class RecyclerItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView albumTitle, numberOfPic;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public RecyclerItemViewHolder(View itemView, TextView albumTitle, TextView numberOfPic, ImageView imageView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.albumTitle = albumTitle;
        this.numberOfPic = numberOfPic;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    public static RecyclerItemViewHolder newInstance(View parent){
        TextView albumTitle=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.album_main_title_textview);
        TextView numberOfPic=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.number_of_pic_textview);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)parent.findViewById(R.id.no_image_placeholder);
        return new RecyclerItemViewHolder(parent,albumTitle,numberOfPic,imageView);
    }
    public void setAlbumTitle(String albumStringArray){ albumTitle.setText(albumStringArray); }

    public void setNumberOfPic(String numberOfPicSetter){
        numberOfPic.setText(numberOfPicSetter);
    }

    public void setImageView(int imageId){
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId);
    }

    public void setImageView(Bitmap bitmap){

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
```

}

And the items are feeded into the RecyclerView using a item feeder class.

```
public class RecyclerItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    private TextView albumTitle, numberOfPic;
    private ImageView imageView;

    public RecyclerItemViewHolder(View itemView, TextView albumTitle, TextView numberOfPic, ImageView imageView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.albumTitle = albumTitle;
        this.numberOfPic = numberOfPic;
        this.imageView = imageView;
    }

    public static RecyclerItemViewHolder newInstance(View parent){
        TextView albumTitle=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.album_main_title_textview);
        TextView numberOfPic=(TextView)parent.findViewById(R.id.number_of_pic_textview);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView)parent.findViewById(R.id.no_image_placeholder);
        return new RecyclerItemViewHolder(parent,albumTitle,numberOfPic,imageView);
    }
    public void setAlbumTitle(String albumStringArray){ albumTitle.setText(albumStringArray); }

    public void setNumberOfPic(String numberOfPicSetter){
        numberOfPic.setText(numberOfPicSetter);
    }

    public void setImageView(int imageId){
        imageView.setImageResource(imageId);
    }

    public void setImageView(Bitmap bitmap){

        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }


}
```

This is how I achieved showing the file folders in RecyclerView and using the CardView as Layout.

Sorry for late reply.
And I am Thankful for @Hendra and @Sandeep for their help.